# Highcharts not defined on highcharts-more.js file

Tags: highcharts

I have the minified `highcharts-more.js` and the error is ocurring in the last piece of code:

Declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/highcharts/highcharts.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js" async></script>
```

And the last piece of code:

```
return d})})()})(Highcharts);
```

`Highcharts` is pointed as not defined.

[image]

Already tried a couple of things but can't make this work.

Comment: My guess it is the `async` loading. Probably getting the `more` file before the main `highcharts.js` library.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro have you tried the above solution (changing from `async` to regular loading)?